# With anonymous function in C# 4.0 why can't I define a delegate inline

Tags: c#, c, language-features

What are the pro cons with having delegates having a reserved definition type.

For example in c if I want to define a function that takes a pointer to a function I can simply define

```
void F(bool (*pFn)(int));
```

In c# I have to take the extra step of first defining the delegate type similar if I had to create a typedef in c before I could define the above function

```
delegate bool del(int s);
void F(del d){...}
```

I find the c# style to bee less clear and flexible.

A: Am I not realizing that this is doable in C# 
B: Would this be a poor language feature to add by introducing the complexity of c type declaration system.

---

Let me clarify I know the fucn is available i'w wondering if there is a way to define an arbitrary delegate.

Comment: I think this is doable in .net 3.5 with Func class.

Comment: What if I want 10 parameters isn't the func class just a predefined delegate.  I know that func<t1,t2,t3,t4> exists is there an arbitrary one

Comment: I don't know the answer to that but having 10 parameters or more than a 4-5 parameters doesn't look good. It might be better wrapping parameters into some kind of a logical structure (e.g. EventArgs)

Comment: It's also worth noting that C# is not by design a functional language. It has some welcome functional constructs but if you want a language that is designed from scratch with this in mind, check out F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534303.aspx) in .NET 3.5 will let you have up to 4 in parameters and 1 return value. [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402862(VS.100).aspx) in .NET 4 will let you have up to 16 in parameters and 1 return value. If you need more than that you probably should get a quantum computer.

Also Action has the same limits in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4 with the exception of the return value.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
void F(Func<int, bool> d){...}
```